# Multiple Increment & Decrement Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, increment, decrement

Basically I have four timepickers, one for startTime and one for endTime. For start time, it's separated into startHour and startMin and same goes to endTime. Here is how I set up my startTime:

```
    htmlStr += "<tr><td><input type='button' id='startHourPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' onClick='plusHour();' /><input type='button' id='startMinPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' onClick='plusMin();' /><br/>";
htmlStr += "<input type='text' id='startHour' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' /><input type='text' id='startMin' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' /><br/>";
htmlStr += "<input type='button' id='startHourMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity'  onClick='minusHour();'/><input type='button' id='startMinMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity'  onClick='minusMin();' /></td>";
```

And for the endTime:

```
htmlStr += "<td><input type='button' id='endHourPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' onClick='plusHour();' /><input type='button' id='endMinPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' onClick='plusMin();' /><br/>";
htmlStr += "<input type='text' id='endHour' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' /><input type='text' id='endMin' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' /><br/>";
htmlStr += "<input type='button' id='endHourMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' onClick='minusHour();' /><input type='button' id='endMinMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' onClick='minusMin();' /></td></tr>";
```

When the plus and minus is clicked, it shares the same function. Here is my JavaScript:

```
function plusHour() {
e.preventDefault();
// Get the field name
fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
// Get its current value
var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
// If is not undefined
if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    // Increment
    if (currentVal < 24) {
        $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    }
}
// Otherwise put a 0 there
$('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
}
function plusMin() {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        // Increment
        if (currentVal < 60) {
            $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
        }
    }
    // Otherwise put a 0 there
    $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
}
function minusHour() {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        // Decrement one
        $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
}
function minusMin() {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        // Decrement one
        $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
}
```

Here is my fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPEC2/) The first and second are for the startTime, the last two are for the endTime.

However, when I click on the increment and decrement button on either start or end time, the textbox does not shows value. I wonder which part that I did wrongly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you simply get the value using `$(this).val()` instead of `var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());` ?

Comment: a fiddle would actually help.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BPEC2/

Comment: Always use `parseInt` with its 2nd parameter to make sure you are not getting unexpected values in return. `parseInt(myVal,10)` for decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

- Since you're using `e.preventDefault();` You need to declare `e`

  ```
  function plusHour() {
   e= window.event;
  ```
- Also, you're attaching the click handler inline, so inside the handler,`this` will refer to the `window` object. you need to pass the element's reference explicitly as follows

  ```
  <input type='button' id='startHourPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' onClick='plusHour(this);' />
  ```

  which you can access in the function like

  ```
  function plusHour(elm) { //elm now refers to clicked element
   e= window.event;
   e.preventDefault();
   // Get the field name
   fieldName = $(elm).attr('field');
  ```
- Then there's problem with your logic - at the end of each function, you're simply setting  the text box values to 0,

  ```
  $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
  ```

  which should be inside an `else` condition.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/BPEC2/1/)

Comment: But I need to set it one by one. not all at once. So I have to create 8 methods instead of just 4?

Comment: @9Dollars99Cents "However, when I click on the increment and decrement button on either start or end time, the textbox does not shows value. I wonder which part that I did wrongly." i hope the answer covers the question. we're not here to code the entire application for you… you're simply asking new questions based on the result you got from an answer that fixed the current issues, without even up voting it… which is not at all encouraging to help you any further...

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove e.preventDefault();. It is preventing script execution with error as there is no object e.

2) All your text boxes have same name "quantity". In the code you are accessing your element using input name. Isn't that ambiguous ? Which input value it will use? Change it to input id which is unique for the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/849/

I just actually edited your previous post and I think it will help you.

This is my first form

```
<form id='myform1' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
```

This is my second form

```
<form id='myform2' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity1' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity1' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity1' />
</form>
```

I change the name of inputs and the field so where ever buttons the user click the field pass will be the inputs where you want to change the change the value.

I hope it will help you. just see the sample code and analyze it.

Comment: Okay sure, thanks a lot. I'd solved it but I don't think it's the best solution as I repeat function just for start and end time.

Comment: It's the same concept. The important thing is that you use the same function in different inputs and give you the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to make single function for all your operations:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#startHourPlus,#startMinPlus,#endHourPlus,#endMinPlus,#startHourMinus,#startMinMinus,#endHourMinus,#endMinMinus").click(function()
            {
                var operation = $(this).val(); // + or -
                var currentField = $("#" + $(this).attr("field"));              
                var currValue = parseInt(currentField.val());
                // Determine whether its PLUS or MINUS operation
                if(operation == "+")
                {               
                    if (!isNaN(currValue))
                    {   
                        // If its hours, limit it to 24 as max
                        if($(this).attr("field").contains("Hour"))
                        {
                            if(currValue < 24)
                                $(currentField).val(currValue+1);
                            else
                                $(currentField).val(0);
                        }
                        // If its mins, limit it to 60 as max
                        else if($(this).attr("field").contains("Min"))
                        {
                            if(currValue < 60)
                                $(currentField).val(currValue+1);
                            else
                                $(currentField).val(0);
                        }

                    }
                }
                else if(operation == "-")
                {
                    if (!isNaN(currValue) && currValue > 0) 
                        $(currentField).val(currValue-1);
                    else
                        $(currentField).val(0);
                }

            });
        });
```

=====================================================

And your HTML will look something like below(added few Id and removed onClicks):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='button' id='startHourPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='txtstartHour'/>
            <input type='button' id='startMinPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='txtstartMin' />
            <br/>
            <input type='text' id='txtstartHour' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
            <input type='text' id='txtstartMin' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
            <br/>
            <input type='button' id='startHourMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='txtstartHour' />
            <input type='button' id='startMinMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='txtstartMin' />
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type='button' id='endHourPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='txtendHour' />
            <input type='button' id='endMinPlus' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='txtendMin' />
            <br/>
            <input type='text' id='txtendHour' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
            <input type='text' id='txtendMin' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
            <br/>
            <input type='button' id='endHourMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='txtendHour' />
            <input type='button' id='endMinMinus' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='txtendMin' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let me know if it works for you. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r5LL3/)

Comment: Not sure why it does not work. I checked it before posting here. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/r5LL3/1/

Comment: How did it go @9Dollars99Cents? You were able to test it? If not through fiddle, you can copy paste above code in your local html copy and see.

Comment: I did solved it by initiating each input by different id. Then when there is any event triggered, it will call different method. For example, startHour plus & minus, startMin plus & minus and so for endHour & endMin. So I got 8 functions in total. I not sure this is a smart way to do this but somehow it works. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. It will work as separate functions with no doubts. However, above i have created single function which will trigger the event as if it is handling 8 different buttons. Anyways, whichever way is easier for you to comprehend is better one. Happy coding.

Comment: I would like to try with single function to handle 8 different buttons. But could you please make the fiddle works?

Comment: Fiddle still not working for you? Surprised. Did you try the new URL that I pinged previously? http://jsfiddle.net/r5LL3/1/embedded/result/